# Thunderbird - Bulk Contacting Saving

Tags: email, thunderbird, contacts

I have a folder with 400+ emails is there away that I can save the "from" e-mail addresses in a bulk matter or do I have to go and save each one,

I would like to add them to a list.

Answer (score 0):

How about this add-on : https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/thunderbird/addon/email-address-crawler/ You can then export your address book.